# How to make printer to print out all textFields

Tags: java, swing

I just started my programmer journey and try to put together a simple windows application.
I'm trying to make a application where you have 3 text fields and can simply print the inputted information on a paper by pressing "print" button.
I'm struggling to get information from all 3 fields to be printed out by pressing "print".
Code below shows my progress. I was trying to add `textField.print(); textField_1.print(); textField_2.print();` but that only made "print" button to trigger 3 different tasks of printing action.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class app {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    app window = new app();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public app() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        textField.setBounds(111, 31, 333, 27);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        textField_1.setBounds(111, 90, 333, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        
        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        textField_2.setBounds(111, 146, 333, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Text1:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(20, 30, 78, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Text2:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(20, 89, 78, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Text3:");
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(20, 145, 78, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
        
        JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
        btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try
                {
                    textField.print();
                    textField_1.print();
                    textField_2.print();
                }
                catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e)
                {
                    System.err.format("No Printer Found", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        btnPrint.setBounds(348, 250, 96, 52);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPrint);
        
        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(null);
                textField_1.setText(null);
                textField_2.setText(null);
            }
        });
        btnClear.setBounds(111, 250, 96, 52);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnClear);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to add another, invisible [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and in the _print_ button's `ActionListener`, set the text of the invisible `JTextComponent` to the concatenation of the text in the `JTextField`s and call method `print` on the `JTextComponent`. Does that fulfill your requirement?

Comment: [Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) from a Swing application is very complex.

Comment: Abra, it sounds really good and make sense. Its just that I'm not sure how correctly execute it. If u have time to dumb it down for me and add it in code I posted, it would be much easier for me to understand and see how it should be done.